# Vue Router 4 - how to combine route with pretty path and params?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

Previous vue router versions had support for having pretty urls with combined props:

```
{ name: "item-editor", path: '/item/:id', component: ItemEditor, props: (route) => {
  return {
    id: Number(route.params.id),
    initParentItemId: Number(route.params.initParentItemId),
  }
}}
```

... which could be accessed with ...

```
this.$router.push({ name: "item-editor", params: {
  id: item.id || 0,
  initParentItemId: initParentItemId
}});
```

This would set browser to "/item/123", but also pass parameters as props.

On Vue Router code above seems to only pass id-parameter, but initParentItemId is not included within route.params.

Is this still somehow possible with Vue Router 4?

**EDIT - one solution & additional details on problem**

As stated, code above used to work on previous vue-router, but is a mixed-bag and probably bad practice. Following solution is easier to understand:

```
{ name: "item-editor", path: '/item/:id', component: ItemEditor, props: (route) => {
    return {
        id: Number(route.query.id),
        initParentItemId: Number(route.query.initParentItemId),
    }
}},
```

```
this.$router.push({
    name: "item-editor", query: {
        initParentItemId: initParentItemId
    },
    params: {
        id: item.id || 0
    }
});
```

... leads to #/item/0?initParentItemId=20 , which is exactly what I was looking for, BUT this is only half-an-answer, because parameter is passed as query-parameter. Usually this is ok, but how about if/when I need to pass object as an parameter?